# batch processing of requests in Kie Server(drools)

Tags: drools, kie

We already have mechanism to call kie server with one request(request containing record with serveral facts) at a time using kie-server REST-API.  This is working fine and gives us response, runs rules and provides audit trail.

However, we have a new requirement of processing requests in batch mode.  We are exploring following options:

Option-1. Receive a batch of requests and send one record at a time to the KIE-SERVER REST API.
Option-2. Send bunch all records in batch together and submit to KIE-SERVER REST API as one request.

Option-1 is really not a solution as it uses one request at a time under the hood.

Question: Is there any batch processing feature offered by KIE-SERVER where in it receives a batch of records (instead of one record in a request), processes each record in isolation (i.e. facts from one record should not mix with other records) and generates response and audit trail?

Comment: I haven't looked at the API for some time, but isn't there a way to bundle commands into a sequence so that you might clean up after each insert?

Answer (score 0):

To execute a batch of commands in one request, `org.kie.api.command.KieCommands` has factory methods and `newBatchExecution()` is what you want.

Obtain the `KieCommands` instance from `KieServices`:

```
KieCommands commandsFactory = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();
```

Make a List of commands using the commands factory methods (e.g. `newInsert(fact)`) and pass it to `newBatchExecution()`:

```
List<Command<?>> commands = makeCommands();
BatchExecutionCommand bec = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(commands);
```

Note that KIE Server will execute the commands in the list order, so sequence them carefully; e.g. don't fire rules before inserting facts.

Use the BatchExecutionCommand instance in the request instead of your single commands.